# Can't kill node js process using grunt dev?

Tags: node.js, process, cygwin, gruntjs, kill

I am currently running a web application that uses GruntJS to run the web app. I normally type `grunt dev` to start it and I can look at it via my local host. When I exit out out of the process using `Ctrl + Z` (I am using Cygwin on Windows 7), I exit normally because Cygwin "hangs" as grunt dev runs. This is what it outputs when it works properly:

```
Running "shell:nodeStart" (shell) task
INFO: Configuration Override: CONFIG.MONGO.URL_CONNECTION : OK
INFO: Running in single node environment
INFO: MongoDB is ready
info: socket.io started

[1]+  Stopped                 grunt dev
```

However, when I make changes to the code and then type `grunt dev` again, Cygwin doesn't hang--it simply goes back to the command line, which I am not sure why. Below is a photo of what happens:

```
Running "shell:nodeStart" (shell) task
INFO: Configuration Override: CONFIG.MONGO.URL_CONNECTION : OK
INFO: Running in single node environment
INFO: MongoDB is ready
```

I noticed that `info: socket.io started` did not occur which led me to type in `ps` to see what processes were running and then I found that my `nodejs` process was still running. When I tried to kill it, it says that there is no process found with my PID.

```
$ ps
  PID    PPID    PGID     WINPID   TTY     UID    STIME COMMAND
 4112    2768    4112       1208  pty0    1000 13:28:47 /usr/bin/ps
 5336       1    5336       5336  ?       1000 13:10:29 /usr/bin/mintty
 2768    5336    2768       3400  pty0    1000 13:10:29 /usr/bin/bash
 7688       1    7708       7788  pty0    1000 13:13:54 /cygdrive/c/Program Files/nodejs/node
```

This is what happens when I try to kill it:

```
$ kill -9 7688
-bash: kill: (7688) - No such process
```

If anyone has any idea on how to kill this process so I can restart my webapp without having to constantly restart my computer, that would be great! Thanks!

EDIT: I have figured out the solution at least for myself. I am not sure why kill doesn't work on cygwin, but when I end the process on Task Manager, grunt dev works as it should. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I have figured out the solution. I'm not sure why when I try to kill the task on cygwin, it doesn't work, but when I open Task Manager and manually delete the process, it runs fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `/bin/kill` instead of the built-in `kill`.

```
/bin/kill -f 7688
```

Comment: I have tried that and it says:
`/bin/kill -f 7688`
`kill: couldn't kill pid 7788, 5`

I'm not sure why the PID changes... But I do notice that the WINPID is 7788.

Comment: It simply says there is no process `7688`. Any other tips? I guess I'd just like to know in general.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Try `kill -9 7788`.